# How to display the content of array list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to display index together with the string. This is what I have tried.

```
 Dim strA As String = "Bell-in-hospital"
 Dim i As Integer = 1

 Dim arrayList() As String = strA.Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For index As Integer = 0 To arrayList.Length - 1
    MsgBox("location:" & arrayList(index) & arrayList.ToString())
    index += 1
Next
```

Now, I'm stuck at For each on how can I display the index together with content. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you tried `For index As Integer = 0 To arrayList.Length - 1`?

Comment: You have to use a for, not a for each

Comment: Ive edited my code, is that correct? @Fabio

Comment: why? @Babbillumpa

Comment: Look at Fabio's answer and you will see. However Eugene solution is also an option.

Comment: `arrayList` is a poor choice for the variable name because there is actually an antiquated collection type called ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Dim strA As String = "Bell-in-hospital"
        'index starts from 0 in arrays
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Dim arrayList() As String = strA.Split({"-"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each test As String In arrayList
        MsgBox("Index: "& i &" String:  "& test)
        'increase index
        i = i + 1
        Next
```

Comment: Variable `i` is redundant, `For Next` loop will increment index automatically

Comment: @Fabio **i**  is not redundant since we are using **For Each** Not **For Next** . Thank you..

Comment: why is i redundant? @Fabio

Comment: Does that mean i will be redundant if we use For Next? @EugeneOgongo

Comment: @lara, it will be redundant when you are using `For Next`, Use `For Each` loop when you don't need index and want just to enumerate all collection items. Every loop has own purpose and using it correctly will save your and others time, especially others time when they will read your code.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to loop array with corresponding index use [For...Next Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement)

```
For index As Integer = 0 To arrayList.Length - 1
    MsgBox($"index: {index}, value: {arrayList(index)}")
Next
```